# Give an equation of the plane parallel to $3x-12y+4z=0$ and tangent to the surface $x^2+y^2+z^2=676$

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Give an equation of the plane parallel to $3x-12y+4z=0$ and tangent to the surface $x^2+y^2+z^2=676$

What I tried:
the normal vector is:
$$
[3,-12, 4]
$$
From the equation:
$$
[2x_0, 2y_0, 2z_0]
$$
It seems, that the tangent point is:
$$
P\left(\frac{3}{2}, -6, 2\right)
$$
but it's not and I don't know why.

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$P\left(\frac{3}{2}, -6, 2\right)$ is not on the sourface.

Note that the gradient is not necessarily equal to the normal, is just proportional. Solve

$$[2x_0, 2y_0, 2z_0]= \lambda [3,-12, 4]$$

and check for which values of $\lambda$ the solution is on your surface.

Comment: ok, I understand :), but how to solve this equation? Could you suggest?

Comment: @TomDavies92 $2x_0=3\lambda \Rightarrow x_0=??$ and so on. Then you need $x_0^2+y_0^2+z_0^2=676$. If you replace $x_0,y_0,z_0$ you end up with an equation of the type  $\lambda^2=...$

Comment: working ! Thank you very much :) Accepted :).